# How to write csv file to another csv file if column values equal to?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a csv file pInfo.csv

```
id,state,rank,amount,area
74,GA,Bronze,298.62,7
263,FL,Diamond,421.43,60
33,IL,Silver,361.69,5
```

I am using pandas to try and write only all the files that contain rank of Silver to a new file.

So something like

```
df = pd.read_csv("pInfo.csv")
    if df['rank'].values == "Silver":
        df.to_csv('newInfo.csv')
```

I get an error "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

This is my first time working with pandas so any help or approach is appreciated.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to copy all rows with rank == 'Silver' only to a new CSV file, correct?

Comment: yes so all rows rank of Silver output to new file would be something like id,state,rank,amount,area
74,GA,Silver,298.62,7
263,FL,Silver,421.43,60
33,IL,Silver,361.69,5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just this should do:

```
df = df[df['rank'] == 'Silver']
df.to_csv('newInfo.csv', index=False)
```

CSV file:

```
id,state,rank,amount,area
33,IL,Silver,361.69,5
```

Comment: Thank you exactly what I am looking for. May I ask why we are using  [[]] here?

Comment: That's one way to use filters on a DataFrame. You can also use df.loc[] instead.

Comment: You can mark this as the answer and consider upvoting if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `.loc` function:

`df.loc[df['rank'] == 'Silver'].to_csv(my_filename, index=False)`

works fine for me.

The reason for the error you got is that `df['rank'].values == "Silver"` returns an array of booleans. You cannot use `if` with an array like that. The suggestions in the error are `any()` or `all()`, which return `True` if *any* value in the array is `True`, or if *all* values are `True`, respectively.

Using the `.loc[]` functionality allows you to select only those rows (or columns) that satisfy the conditions you need.